# Why does sorting a collection have O(n log n) complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Reading through https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort, it states "Complexity: O(n log n), where n is the length of the collection," but I don't have an intuition for why this exactly this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question of  why the algorithm implemented by *that particular* function requires time $O(n \log n)$ should be asked to whoever wrote that function (in the documentation they do not mention any particular algorithm).

That said, there are several comparison-based sorting algorithms that require $O(n \log n)$ comparisons (and hence $O(n \log n)$ time to sort elements that can be compared in $O(1)$ time). See, for example, [Heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) or [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

If you are confused about why sorting cannot be done (asymptotically) faster, then notice that the function you referenced implements some (unspecified) comparison-based sorting algorithm. There is a [lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list) of $\Omega(n \log n)$ on the number of comparisons required by *any* comparison-based sorting algorithm. Essentially, since the algorithm needs to be able to output all $n!$ permutations of the input list, it needs to branch at least $\log n! = \Omega(n \log n)$ times.